Ubuntu 24.04 freezes/hangs after sharing my screen on zoom/slack/discord/google meets
The Problem

Ubuntu freezes after I try screensharing. I've tried sharing on multiple different applications including zooom, slack, google meets and discord. Each time, screen sharing works normally for a minute or 2 but then the screen freezes and I cant use my keyboard or mouse for input. As a result I am forced to hold the power button down on my pc and power it on again.
What I've tried so far:


I've tried clearing and installing ubuntu again. I've also stayed away from flatpaks and used purely snaps. I still get the same error.

I've tried looking online for support but the solutions require using the keyboard and doing Alt + SysRq + R + E + I + S + U + B. However, I am unable to use any input. What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?

I've looked into updating the bios too from here https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre-m-series-desktops/thinkcentre-m700-tiny/10hy/10hy002puk/pc0at6gj/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI&id=5AC6A815-321D-440E-8833-B07A93E0428C but it says you need windows to install?? I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I've tried switching from wayland to xorg as suggested in this article: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://medium.com/@edouard.courty/how-to-fix-screen-sharing-on-ubuntu-22-04-disabling-wayland-e9eac4143c7#:~:text=This%20problem%20is%20identified%20to,anything%20to%20the%20system%20display. but I still get the error.


Have a suspicion it may have something to do with the low amount of RAM (8 GB) on my system.
Here's some info about my system:

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-07-02 21:03:41

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Lenovo ThinkCentre M700
Memory:                                      8.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i3-6100T × 4
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
Disk Capacity:                               240.1 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            FWKTAFA
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-36-generic

Important logs

20:38:12 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2391.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
20:38:11 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
20:37:29 (uetoothd): src/device.c:set_wake_allowed_complete() Set device flags return status: Invalid Parameters
20:37:26 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-16)
20:37:25 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
20:37:25 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.

After doing free:

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         8018936     2110760     4618924      397572     1936228     5908176
Swap:        4194300           0     4194300

Any help would be appreciated, I really like everything else about ubuntu and would love to continue using it.
Edit: I tried using other linux distros, including debaian, linux mint, fedora, and I still got the same problem. I installed windows again and screen sharing works fine there on zoom and google meets. I have a feeling it may be a hardware problem.
Also I tried re installing ubuntu again but it froze during installation so i gave up.

Do you have swap? free will tell you and us.  If not, you need between 1xRAM and 2xRAM. Please [edit] your Question to add this information.  Do not use Add Comment.
